# add either check box, list box or radio button in one of the cells in each row in a flex table

Tags: google-apps-script

How to add either check box, list box or radio button in one of the cells in each row in a flex table. I am using apps script. i tried following but it only displays the list box in one cell in last row:

```
function doGet(){
    var app = UiApp.createApplication();
    var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
    var listBox = app.createListBox();
    listBox.addItem("Yes").addItem("No").setName("myListBox");
    var table = app.createFlexTable().setId("myTable");

    table.setBorderWidth(1)
    table.setCellPadding(1);

    //Get Data from spreadsheet

    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spreadsheet ID');
    var spreadsheetId = 'Spreadsheet ID';
    var dataArray = getData(spreadsheetId);

    for (var row = 0; row<dataArray.length; row++){
    for (var col = 0; col<dataArray[row].length; col++){

        if( col == 1){
            table.setWidget(row, col, listBox);
        }
    table.setText(row, col, dataArray[row][col].toString());


    }
    } 
    app.add(table);
    return app;
    }

    function getData(spreadsheetId){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0].getDataRange();
    return sheet.getValues();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply forgot to use an "else" in the condition, without "else" the text overwrites the other widgets.

```
  for (var row = 0; row<dataArray.length; row++){
    for (var col = 0; col<dataArray[row].length; col++){
      if( col == 1){
        table.setWidget(row, col, listBox);
       }else{
         table.setText(row, col, dataArray[row][col].toString());
         }
      }
    }
```

**EDIT :** I forgot another point, **even more important** : you can't use the same `listBox` multiple times, you should define a new `listBox` widget each time you add one to the `flexTable`... so place the `app.createListBox` in the `if` condition in the loop and think about giving each of them a different name and Id.